# How to stop the search results from loading the wrong template?

Tags: search, template-hierarchy

I have a custom themed site which is not using the correct page template to display search results.

I inherited the site with the theme and I'm now trying to make some changes; I did not create the theme and I cannot reach the person who did, so I'm on my own.

The theme contains `searchform.php` and `search.php` files but when the search results are displayed it is using the `page.php` template instead. I know this because I placed HTML comments in all the template files to show the file name and I'm seeing `<!-- TEMPLATE: page.php -->` when I inspect the HTML in the browser.

The `searchform.php` contains:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url(  ) ); ?>">
<label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search' ); ?></label>
<input type="text" class="field" name='s' value="Search" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'enter search term' ); ?>" />
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

Common problems I've seen from other people's questions are the form `method` using `POST`, not `GET`, the `action` URL not sending the search terms to the "home" page, and the search text box `name` [being changed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96629/search-uses-index-php-instead-of-search-php-on-renaming-search-field-from-s) from `s` to [something else](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61712/search-php-template-not-loading-results), but none of these have been changed in my case. As far as I can see all the settings for the form are correct.

When submitted the search form results in the following URL:

```
http://www.festivalkidz.com/?s=tent
```

which via the template hierarchy should use `search.php` and if that is not available, use `index.php`. But on my site `page.php` is used, which is not even on the same "path" as the other search result template options as shown in the [Wordpress template hierarchy diagram](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/96/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg).

[image: Wordpress Template Hierarchy]

I have also seen questions about changing the default template using in a theme for certain pages, with the use of rewrite functions and the like. I cannot find anything of that sort in the `functions.php` file of the theme; in fact there are no filters installed at all.

The normal methods of debugging problems are to switch to one of the default themes and see if things work but I cannot use that in this case; I am getting the correct *search results*, just not displayed in the correct *page template* (theme specific problem).

The other usual thing to do is to disable all plug-ins but I don't see how I can do that on a live site without visitors seeing a "messed up" site while I'm testing; and although we're not massively popular I don't want to disrupt any of the 500 or so visitors we get a day: unless there's a way I can do this sort of testing without causing problems?

So I need help in working out *why* the wrong template is being used, what else could cause the site to select a different template?

Comment: "Or can anyone suggest ways to further debug the problem without disrupting the live site?" -- Run the site on a development server and test it there. You should not ever develop on a live site.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I should not be testing on the live site. I guess the wording of my question is a bit misleading, I was hoping for suggestions on tracking down the template problem, not general debugging advice. I'll remove that part of the question. Thanks.

Comment: There are at least half a dozen ways to mess with template loading, not to mention oddball things a theme/plugin might cook up that I am not thinking about. You need to debug this. I don't think it can be guessed at.